# Angularfire2 - Query async not working

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, angularfire2

Good day, I have APP With:

- ionic 3
- Firebase
- Angularfire2

TransactionsPage

- I'm pushing data on button click with current timestamp
- Firebase node: transactions

HomePage

```
var timestamp = Date.now() - 1 * 60 * 1000;  
this.transactions = db.list('/transactions', ref => ref.orderByChild('date').startAt(timestamp)).valueChanges()
```

- `timestamp` is last 1 minute
- `ref.orderByChild('date')` is timestamp pushed from transactionsPage

HTML HomePage

```
 <ion-list no-lines>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let tr of transactions | async">
        <ion-icon color="primary" name="basket" item-start></ion-icon>
          {{tr.date | date:'EEEE, dd MMMM - HH:mm' }} 
      </ion-item> 
 </ion-list>
```

I'm getting list of transactions here, but I need transaction where published last 1 min ago.

list is working, but my problem is the list not hidding and not makes async, if I will wait for 1 min after 1 min list must hidden and if here is other transactions pushed must be shown new ones.

Comment: That is because you initialize your timestamp property, which won't change afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
this.transactions = db.list('/transactions', ref => ref.orderByChild('date').startAt(Date.now() - 1 * 60 * 1000)).valueChanges()
```

So when ever a change happens it will also update the query with current time.